# Store CLRegion attribute in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, core-location

I need to add a CLRegion to my Core Data Entity but I don't what type to select for it.

I read this [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW1) but I'm still confused on how to get it setup correctly. If someone could provide an explanation I'd reall appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the entity attributes type for the CLRegion select "Transformable" Then define what the object is in the the NSManagedObject that Core Data generates for you. (see location below)

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastName;

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLRegion * location;

@end

@implementation Person

@dynamic firstName;
@dynamic lastName;

@dynamic location;

@end
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've tried that before actually and I get this error: Unknown type name 'CLRegion' and another: Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type.

Comment: Duh didn't import CoreLocation. That's just embarrassing. Thanks very much!

Comment: Yay!  The other option was to do this : http://samsoff.es/posts/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding and then store them as a "binary data"